# Cómo obtener un campo de un objeto dentro de una lista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Tengo una clase `Carrito` con 4 propiedades(`codArt, nombre, cantidad, precio`), hice un objCarrito (con sus respectivos valores) y lo metí en una lista:

```
List<Carrito> productos = new List<Carrito>();
productos.Add(objCarrito);
```

Esta lista, la pongo en una variable de sesion.

Ahora bien, lo que quiero hacer es acceder al valor nombre del objCarrito que está dentro de la lista (productos), dentro de la variable.

¿Hay alguna forma menos rebuscada de meter varios valores en una variable de sesion?

Comment: A que te refieres con menos rebuscada? La variable sesión sólo acepta listas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las sesiones en ASP.NET se utilizan para almacenar cualquier información a cerca de la sesión de usuario que este activa en ese momento.

Ahora bien, cuando se dice que almacena cualquier información es por que una sesión trabaja con tipos `object` lo que quiere decir que puedes almacenar cualquier tipo de dato, no solo listas que de pronto es lo que estas planteando.

Para solucionar el problema que estas indicando hay dos opciones, la primera es utilizando la lista que estas creando:

```
List<Carrito> productos = new List<Carrito>();
productos.Add(objCarrito);
Session["lista"] = productos;

// Para obtener el valor puedes hacer lo siguiente
var nombre = ((List<Carrito>)Session["lista"])[0].nombre;
```

La otra opción es que no utilices una lista, si no que simplemente guardas el objeto en la sesión directamente:

```
Session["objeto"] = objCarrito;
var nombre = ((Carrito)Session["objeto"]).nombre;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora, una cosita más: cómo podria volcar la variable sesion en un gridview?

Comment: Para trabajar con el gridview entonces tendrías que utilizar la lista y seria algo mas o menos así `gridView1.DataSource = (List<Carrito>)Session["lista"];` y la siguiente línea de código seria `gridView1.DataBind();`. Si no ejecutas el DataBind no puedes ver los registros.

Comment: Lo hice y me muestra solamente el ultimo registro cargado en la sesion.. De la forma en que lo trabajaba antes(y los demas grids), iba cargando los datos en un dataSet y luego los pasaba al dataSource del Grid.. Cómo podría hacer eso en este caso?

Comment: Realmente no necesitas pasar la información a un DataSet, de la manera que te indique debería funcionar correctamente, es mas depende como este estructurado tu programa la `session` también sobraría. Deberias verificar que la lista se esté llenando correctamente antes de establecerla al Grid y  esto lo puedrias hacer ejecutando la aplicación en modo depuración y luego verificando que las variables tengan los datos correctos.

Comment: Utilice el modo depuracion y el problema está al guardar los datos, debería hacer una nueva pregunta y poner el codigo para solucionarlo, verdad? O edito esta? Gracias

Comment: Si lo mejor es que crees una nueva pregunta y pongas el código donde se te está presentando el problema